# Java - Background song to my game (How can I add it)

Tags: java, applet, audio

I'm trying to create a game and I'm currently trying to add sounds to it but due to lack of experience I failed to do so so I'm asking for your help.
How can I add a background song to my game?

Comment: Do you want certain sounds to trigger when something happens in game or general background music that plays randomly or on a loop?

Comment: @user2860598: Both if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start a separate thread for playing sound. In this thread play it. In this way your game will be running and at same time you can run the sound.

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
  // The wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless it blocks on the
  // Clip finishing; see comments.
    public void run() {
      try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
          Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did import that but I can't hear the sound.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void music() {  
            AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;  
            AudioStream BGM;  
            AudioData MD;  
            ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;  

            try {  
                BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("som.wav"));  
                MD = BGM.getData();  
                loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);  
            } catch(IOException error)  {  
                System.out.println("Error!!!");  

            }  
            MGP.start(loop);  
        }
```